# PHP Get Current Time and AM/PM

Tags: php, html, css

How can I get the current time and am/pm using php? What I have does not work

This is what I currently have

```
$format1 = date("G");//this is supposed to get the current hour
$format2 = date("a");//this is supposed to get the current am or pm
$varies = "";//picture url that changes depending on time and am/pm
if(($format1 >=5 && $format1 <9) && ($format2 == "am")){
$varies = "url('Images/5to9am.PNG')";  //changes picture based on time and am/pm  
}
echo "body{ background-image: $varies"; //changes the background
```

Answer (score 2):

You should get familiar with this page:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

In your case `date('G')` returns the *24 hour* format. Which I don't think is what you want.

Try `date('g')` for 12 hour format, if you're going to look at it alongside am/pm.

Alternatively, keep the 24 hour format, and ignore am/pm.

```
$hour = date("G"); // 24 hour format
if($hour >= 5 && $hour < 9) {
   // It's between 5am and 9am!!
```

Comment: Either my brain isn't working or that logic should never evaluate to true? If `$hour` is `8`, then the first half would be `true` and the latter `false` meaning you would end up with `false` since you're using `&&`

Comment: @Pigeon ha, typo. Thanks.

Comment: @SmartyCoder Ah that makes sense, I thought I was going into a meltdown after a long day at work ;_;

Answer (score 0):

Here date function give you hours b'coz you are passing `H`  as argument.And $time variable have all time hours.

Based on  server time or site time I would show a different background image at different times of the day.

- 6am-10am - sunrise.jpg
- 10am-5pm - day.jpg
- 5pm-7pm- sunset.jpg
- 7pm-6am- night.jpg

**PHP Code :**

```
<?php 

$time = date("H");    

if( $time >= 06 && $time < 10 )

    $img_name = 'sunrise.jpg';

if( $time >= 10 && $time < 17 )

    $img_name = 'day.jpg';

if( $time >= 17 && $time < 19 )

    $img_name = 'sunset.jpg';

if( $time >= 19 && $time < 6 )

    $img_name = 'night.jpg';

?>

<style>

    .my-class{background-image:url('http://yoursite.com/images/<?php echo $img_name;?>');}

</style>
```